# Update text in DB with more than one line without <br>

Tags: sql, database, sql-update, line

I have a problem with updating text in my DB.
I would like my text like this in DB:

```
"Test test test
 test test
 test test"
```

And not like this:

```
"Test test test<br>
 test test<br>
 test test"
```

And still have more lines than one..

Comment: What's the problem?  why can't you do that?

Comment: When you display it, replace `\n` by `<br>`.

Comment: In my DB should there be no <br>

Answer (score 0):

You could just remove `<br>`, but it looks like it's safer to only remove the ones at the end of a line. `CHR` is sometimes called `CHAR` and concatenation is done with `||` (oracle), `+` (many) or `&`.

```
UPDATE ... SET ... = REPLACE( ... , '<br>' || CHR(13) || CHR(10), CHR(13) || CHR(10) );
```